# Usar lista como valor de dicionário usando método append() Python

Tags: python, lista, hash

Tenho algum dicionário em python, e desejo atribuir uma lista como valor para cada chave do dicionário, porém preciso utilizar o método append() para acrescentar elementos, porém depois de acrescentar os elementos na lista, o valor da chave é None.

Ex:

```
dic = {}
lista = []
dic['a'] = lista.append('a')
print dic

{a:None}
```

Como resolvo esse problema ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método `append` não retorna valor, por isso sua chave tem como valor `None`. A maneira correta é a seguinte:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> lista = []
>>> dic['a'] = lista
>>> lista.append('a')
>>> print dic
{'a': ['a']}
```

Ou, se preferir, essa maneira é mais direta:

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> dic['a'] = []
>>> dic['a'].append('a')
>>> print dic
{'a': ['a']}
>>>
```

Comment: Excelente contribuição Magnun Leno!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> lis = [1, 2, 3]
>>> dic['num'] = lis[:] #criando cópia não gera vinculo com a lista
>>> print(dic)

{'num': [1,2,3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como já explicado o método `append()` não retorna valor e portanto na linha:

```
dic['a'] = lista.append('a')
```

A chave `dic['a']` é atribuída como `None`.

Caso todos os valores de seu dicionário sejam listas, o [módulo collections](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html) inclui subclasses especializadas de containers que facilitam a codificação.
A classe [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) é uma subclasse de [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) que chama uma função factory para fornecer os valores não encontrados.

No exemplo é passado a referência do constructor [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) como função factory para `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)
dic['a'].append('a')
dic['a'].append('b')
dic['a'].append('c')

print(dic)
#defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
```